# Http post json (Spring/angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, json, spring, http, post

[i create an spring/angularjs application but i have some problems with "post",when i tried to test the controller without angularjs
i had this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjAMa.jpg)

[this is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58tWr.jpg)

[this my angularjs app][3]

```
$scope.ajouter_employe=function(){
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "/employe1",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data: {idEmploye: $scope.idEmploye}
    }).then( function(response){
                   alert('yes');
                 });



}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/employe1", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
```

Add `consumes` and `produces` to your controller's RequestMapping

Comment: it doesn't work
still have this message when i try to test my controller :
{
"timestamp": 1495521855274,
"status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
"message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryShaAnQBDa47tg35j' not supported",
"path": "/employe1"
}
when i try  "get" it work correctly!!